# How to best recover archived folder which appears as a file on NTFS drive?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, data-recovery, synctoy

I archived a folder to an external HDD and kept it in sync with another one using Sync Toy. Now I see that the folder appears as a 0 byte file on both HDDs. Everything else is fine and readable.
I am using Windows 7 64bit Home Premium and NTFS on all disks.
Is checkdisk safe or should I try some recovery tools first? How would you approach this issue?

Comment: Make sure to have full, BIT-BY-BIT backup in place first! You could use something like: http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a free (for personal use) tool named [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) which managed to find those lost folders and files successfully. I only lost names of some folders and files.

Also ran the Windows tool Check Disk which found no problems whatsoever. Odd.
Looks like Sync Toy is not to blame here.